# preventing user from entering certain characters while allowing others using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me with this problem... oddly enough it works up until:

```
if (key < 48 || key > 57){ //if it is not a number ascii code
        //Prevent default action, which is inserting character
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
    }
```

Which prevents the user from entering any value that isn't a number. The code following that is attempting to allow the user to use characters such as tab and delete. For some reason it isnt working and it seems like it should logically..

Please Help or provide me with a more up to date answer/good guide on how to achieve this..

Thanks,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="homepagecontainer">
<div class="" style="margin:auto; width 600px;">
<form action="registration.php" method="post" name = "register" >
  <div style="width:50%; margin:auto;">
    <h1>Register</h1>
<button style = "width:100px;float:right;display:inlineblock;"onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button><br><br><br>

<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>

    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="username"><b>Username:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="[^-,]+" onKeyDown="ValidateName()" >

    <label style="width:50%" for="fname"><b>First Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name"  pattern="[^-,]+" name="fname">

    <label for="lname"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ender Last Name" pattern="[^-,]+" name="lname"><br><br>

    <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth</b></label>
    <input type="date" placeholder="" name="dob" pattern="[^-,]+"> <br><br>

    <label for="ingame"><b>In Game Name:</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter In Game Name" name="ingame" pattern="[^-,]+">

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" pattern="[^-,]+">

    <label for="pw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pw" pattern="[^-,]+">

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="confpw" pattern="[^-,]+">
    <hr>

    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
    <button onclick="" name="register" type="submit" class="register">Register</button>
  </div>

  <div <div style="width:50%; margin;auto;">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in (unfinished)</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<div style="margin:auto;">
</body>
<footer>
    <p class="copyright">© Copyright 2019 Daniel Violante except where noted
Privacy Policy | Terms of Service
Endless Online © Copyright Vult-r Studios 
</p>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
</html>

<script>
function ValidateName() {
    var e = event || window.event;  // get event object
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which; // get key cross-browser

if (key < 48 || key > 57){ //if it is not a number ascii code
        //Prevent default action, which is inserting character
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = false;
    }
    if (key=8 || key==46 || key == 9 || key==17 || key==91 || key==18 || 
            key==116 || key==89 || key==67 || key==88 || key==35 || key==36)
            return true;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("input").on("input", function(){
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

This will replace non-numeric characters with nothing.

## How this works

Add a event listener to input area. This will be triggered when user makes an input, including paste.

When this is triggered, function will get the value from target input, and replace with user input, but only numeric characters. Any characters which is not numeric will be deleted.

Comment: Where exactly should i place this and what do you mean by this??

Comment: Added explanation. Let me know if anything is missing.